# How to dynamically add columns for Grid ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

I want dynamically load columns for grid from loaded store. 
I used code like in sencha fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lc5&view/editor, it work, but in modern version it dose not work. Because modern version not have `reconfigure` method. 
How can I solve that problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example, the solution is as follows:

```
var grid = Ext.create({
    xtype: 'grid',
    fullscreen: true,
    minHeight: 150,
    renderTo: document.body,
    plugins: {
        gridsummaryrow: true
    },
    store: {
        fields: ['student', 'mark'],
        idProperty: 'student',
        data: [{
            "student": 'Student 1',
            "mark": 84
        }, {
            "student": 'Student 2',
            "mark": 72
        }, {
            "student": 'Student 3',
            "mark": 96
        }, {
            "student": 'Student 4',
            "mark": 68
        }],
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory'
        }
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'student',
        text: 'Name'
    }]
});

grid.getStore().load();

grid.setColumns([{
    width: 200,
    dataIndex: 'student',
    text: 'Name',
    summaryType: 'count',
    summaryRenderer: function(value){
        return Ext.String.format('Number of students: {0}', value);
    }
}, {
    "dataIndex": 'mark',
    "text": 'Mark',
    "summaryType": 'average'
}]);
```

**the most important**

You must define a `column` on the grid `columns`, even though it will be changed at a future time on your grid.

I removed the dependency from your students.json sample file and put the data into an in-memory store to facilitate the demonstration here.

In modern version, you will use `setColumns` method.

[Working Sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2np0) on fiddle.

Comment: Thank you it work, but I want load columns from store

Comment: You can do this in the `callback success` from `Ext.Ajax.request` call in your data source. Do the load `setColumns` with the metadata of the columns. And then load the store with the `loadData` method.

Comment: Ok I added `Ext.getCmp('surveyAnswersGrid').setColumns(meta.columns);` and it work, but raw with data not displayed. I thing need add fields for store. How can I do it?

Comment: calling something lihe this `Ext.getCmp('surveyAnswersGrid').getStore().loadData(meta.data,false)`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
My data look like this: http://joxi.ru/p27BjwVTokgGdm

Comment: you need find the right attribute to access data object. Try put a `debbuger;` before the  ine you call `Ext.getCmp('surveyAnswersGrid').getStore().loadData(meta.data,false)` and you investigate to found solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183794/discussion-between-daniel-da-cunha-bueno-and-a-yushko).

Answer (score 3):

Another option I did is to **bind the columns** after populating them in the controller.

Sample code:

```
{
     xtype: 'gridpanel',
     id: 'user-grid',
     cls: 'user-grid',
     width: '100%',
     scrollable: false,
     bind: {
          store: '{userStore}',
          columns: '{columns}'
     }
}
```

In the controller I populated the columns this way:

```
setUserGridColumns: function () {
    var fields = ['title', 'Surname', 'Profession', 'Age', 'randomValue'];// this can come from server
    var columns = [];
    fields.forEach(element => {
        var column = {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            cls: 'content-column',
            dataIndex: element,
            text: element,
            flex: 1,
            sortable: false,
            align: 'center',
            style: 'border-width:0px !important; margin-bottom:15px'
        }
        columns.push(column);
    });
    this.getViewModel().set('columns', columns);
}
```

Comment: How `setUserGridColumns`  method is associated with the grid. In grid defination what i have to write to get `setUserGridColumns` method.